# spring-boot-maven-plugin with paketo buildpacks does not perform binding in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, spring-boot-maven-plugin, paketo

I am using paketo buildpacks with spring-boot-maven-plugin and I want to copy some files from a specific folder into the image.
If I am running `spring-boot:build-image` locally it works fine and I can inspect the image and see the files there, however, when the image is being built in a Gitlab CI pipeline, doesn't seem to add the files.
The files are checked in so there is no need to download them from somewhere.
I am using Docker socket binding as runner.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
           <builder>docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                <buildpacks>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/adoptium:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/syft:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip:latest</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/image-labels:latest</buildpack>
                </buildpacks>
         <bindings>                          
            <binding>${project.basedir}/src/folder:/workspace/CONTAINER-INF/folder:ro</binding>
         </bindings>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**gitlab_ci.yml**

```
stage: etc
image: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17
variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: '/var/run/docker.sock'
script:
  - mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

Comment: A `<binding>` that is configured like you've done here causes the specified directory to be visible to the buildpacks that are run as part of the CNB build process. This doesn't automatically mean that the directory content will be copied to the generated image. A buildpack would need to do the copy, and it's hard to tell from your example what buildpack might be doing that when you're running locally. Can you give more detail on the types of files that are in the binding and how you expect them to be used?

Comment: Hi @ScottFrederick thanks for your reply, I have updated the question with the list of buildpacks used. The files I am trying to copy are just some text and html files containing licenses.

Comment: I'm not sure what the mechanism is that copies the files from the binding to the generated image, so I'm not sure why it would work in some environments but not others. I've added the `paketo` tag to get the attention of the experts.

Comment: I think that I found my answer "Sharing files and directories from the source repository into containers might not work as expected. Volume mounting is done in the context of the host machine, not the build container." https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#known-issues-with-docker-socket-binding

Comment: and here is the issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28121